# How to set QueryExecutionContext in boto3 when the query contains joining of tables from multiple databases?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-athena

I am using Boto3 package in python3 to execute an Athena query. From the [documentation of Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution), I understand that I can specify a query execution context, i.e. a database name under which the query has to be executed. With a properly specified query execution context, we can omit the fully qualified table name(`db_name.table_name`) from the query and instead use just the table name.

So the query `SELECT * FROM db1.tab1` can be converted to `SELECT * FROM tab1` with `QueryExecutionContext : {'database':'db1'}`

**The problem:** I need to run a query on Athena from python which looks something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM   ((SELECT *
        FROM   db1.tab1 AS Temp1)
        INNER JOIN (SELECT *
                    FROM   db2.tab2 AS Temp2)
                ON temp1.id = temp2.id)
```

As we can see, the query joins tables from two different databases. If I want to omit the database names from this query, how do I specify the `QueryExecutionContext` ?

Comment: QueryExecutionContext accepts only one database.So if you want to run a query across multiple databases then you have to pass fully qualified table name along with database

Comment: @bdcloud That is what I ended up doing. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: CCoder done.Please mark it as answered!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QueryExecutionContext](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_QueryExecutionContext.html) accepts only one database as an argument.So if you want to run a query across multiple databases then you have to pass fully qualified table name along with database.