# How to select multiple athena databases in QueryExecutionContext in python boto3 code when select query contain multiple databases?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-athena

This is the query, I am trying to execute.
The query is getting successfully executed but view is not getting created on Athena.
As in QueryExecutionContext we can specify only 1 database, tried with below fully qualified path but still not creating view.

When I tried keeping both tables in same database then it is creating view. but that's not my use case.

Found something similar here: [How to set QueryExecutionContext in boto3 when the query contains joining of tables from multiple databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851974/how-to-set-queryexecutioncontext-in-boto3-when-the-query-contains-joining-of-tab/59890614#59890614?newreg=cfe365765d584e3a977cf7b8742bf10f)

@CCoder @Prabhakar-Reddy

What changes required in below code?

```
    client = boto3.client('athena',region_name='eu-central-1')
    response = client.start_query_execution(
    
            QueryString = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VIEWNAME_VIEW AS SELECT * FROM DB1.TBNM1 where country_id in (select country from DB2.country)",
    
            QueryExecutionContext={
                'Database': 'DB1'
            },
            ResultConfiguration={
                'OutputLocation': 's3://BUCKETNAME/temp/'
            }
        )
```

Comment: What is the Status of the Query in Athena? Is it failed? What is the error?

Comment: I am executing this query through Airflow , that task is getting executed, but for different databases, it's not creating view. Incase of same DB, it's creating views.

Answer (score 0):

Your query shouldn't fail as is. The context DB is provided as a default and can be qualified in the query, as you are doing.

Comment: Query is not failing, it gets executed successfully. but doesn't create any view. & if same query executed on Athena, then creates view.

Comment: do you see the query in the history? are you running under the same account?

Comment: I am executing this query through Airflow , that task is getting executed, but for different databases, it's not creating view. Incase of same DB, it's creating views.